# Informatica: comparing the date field between two tables

Tags: informatica

i am new in informatica software. now i have two tables, say `AAA` and `BBB` table.

`AAA: last_post_date`

`BBB: Trx_No, Field1, Field2, trx_date`

I want to move `BBB` table to the target table which the trx_date must be greater than last_post_date. I cannot use joiner transformation as it doesnt have >, < , >= and  <= operators. If I want to use lookup transformation, how to use it for this case or any other way can help me do this. I searched many websites about the lookup transformation , still don't know how to use it.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: `AAA` has only 1 row which contains `last_post_date` or there are multiple rows for each run?

Comment: yes. it just one row. AAA contains Id and last_post_date fields only

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `AAA` has only 1 row which contains `last_post_date`. If both the tables are in same database, you can use Source Qualifier override

```
select Trx_No, Field1, Field2, trx_date from BBB where trx_date > last_post_date
```

But if both tables are in different database and / or you are not able to create DB link between them, then use below solution.

- After Source Qualifier for both source, use `Expression` transformation.
- Add an output port in both Expression Transformations, say `o_Dummy` and hardcode the value as `1` (for both transformations)
- Use Joiner and use `normal join`. Join condition would be `o_Dummy = o_Dummy1`.
- After it use a `filer` to filter records where `trx_date > last_post_date`.

This would be your flow.

```
SQ_AAA -> Expression -> Joiner -> Filter -> Target
SQ_BBB -> Expression -^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Source Qualifier to read data from `BBB`, followed by lookup to `AAA` and a filter witha a condition `trx_date>last_post_date`.

Ideally you'd use an unconnected lookup reffered from Expression variable port e.g. `v_LastPostDate = IIF(ISNULL(v_LastPostDate), LKP.LoopkupToAAA, v_LastPostDate)` - this would ensure you perform the lookup only once. Not that it would matter a lot with a single value, but I thought I'll share some good practice :)